# I keep getting error (TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str) when running my code

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to run the code below where I want the daily specials to show when the I choose the day and time but I seem to be getting the error (string indices must be integers, not str) when I run the code. Any help is appreciated.

```
def get_specials():

    monday = {"B": "Horseradish omelet. Note: better than it sounds",
              "L": "Momma's Curry. Note: Can be made spicy.",
              "D": "Beef brisket. Note: COmes with au jus. That's pronounced 'Oh jhoo', not 'Ow Juice'"}
    tuesday = {"B": "Sausage gravy over biscuits. Note: Toast can be subbed",
              "L": "Grilled cheese and tomato soup. Note: We have vegan cheese",
              "D": "Meatloaf. Note: Comes woth catsup on the top. Not optional"}
    wednesday = {"B": "Horseradish omelet. Note: better than it sounds",
                 "L": "Momma's Curry. Note: Can be made spicy.",
                 "D": "Beef brisket. Note: COmes with au jus. That's pronounced 'Oh jhoo', not 'Ow Juice'"}
    thursday = {"B": "Sausage gravy over biscuits. Note: Toast can be subbed",
                "L": "Grilled cheese and tomato soup. Note: We have vegan cheese",
                "D": "Meatloaf. Note: Comes woth catsup on the top. Not optional"}
    friday = {"B": "Horseradish omelet. Note: better than it sounds",
              "L": "Momma's Curry. Note: Can be made spicy.",
              "D": "Beef brisket. Note: COmes with au jus. That's pronounced 'Oh jhoo', not 'Ow Juice'"}
    saturday = {"B": "Sausage gravy over biscuits. Note: Toast can be subbed",
                "L": "Grilled cheese and tomato soup. Note: We have vegan cheese",
                "D": "Meatloaf. Note: Comes woth catsup on the top. Not optional"}

    specials = {"M": "monday",
                "T": "tuesday",
                "W": "wednesday",
                "R": "thursday",
                "F": "friday",
                "St": "saturday"}
    return specials

def print_special(special):
    print "The special is:"
    print special
    print "*"*15

def get_day():
    while True:
        day = raw_input ("Day (M/T/W/R/F/St): ")
        if day.upper() in ["M", "T", "W", "R", "F", "ST"]:
            return day.upper()
        else:
            print "I'm sorry, but {} isn't valid".format(day)

def get_time():
    while True:
        time = raw_input ("Time (B/L/D): ")
        if time.upper() in ["B", "L", "D"]:
            return time.upper()
        else:
            print "I'm sorry, but {} isn't valid".format(time)

def main():
    specials = get_specials()
    print "This script will tell you the specials for any day and time of the week"
    while True:
        day = get_day()
        special = specials[day]
        time = get_time()
        print_special(special[time])
# ********************^^^^ HERE ^^^*
        another = raw_input("Do you want to check another day and time?(Y/N): ")
        if another.lower == "n":
            break

main()
```

The asterisk line is where the issue is at. (the asterisk is not part of the code, it is merely to highlight the error with the specific line) The error shown is below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 62, in <module>
    main()
  line 57, in main
    print_special(special[time])
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: Don't use an asterisk. Give us the full traceback (as text) instead.

Comment: `specials` is a dictionary mapping strings to strings. `'M'` maps to the string `'monday'` for example. In `get_specials`, instead of `"monday"` did you mean to include the *variable* `monday` perhaps?

Comment: @Martin Pieters Yes, I meant to relate "M" to the variable monday. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because `get_specials` returns a dictionary with keys and values both `strings` not with key a `string` and value `dict`. So change the specials dictionary to

```
specials = {"M": monday,
            "T": tuesday,
            "W": wednesday,
            "R": thursday,
            "F": friday,
            "St": saturday}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you do:

```
print_special(special[time])
```

for example:

suppose your dict is:

```
monday = {"B": "Horseradish omelet. Note: better than it sounds",
              "L": "Momma's Curry. Note: Can be made spicy.",
              "D": "Beef brisket. Note: COmes with au jus. That's pronounced 'Oh jhoo', not 'Ow Juice'"}
```

and we want 'B' 's value so you will do:

```
print(monday['B'])
```

But there you are doing:

```
print('monday'['B'])
```

you can check by:

```
day = get_day()
special = specials[day]
time = get_time()
print(type(special))
print(time)
```

ouput:

```
monday
<class 'str'>
B
```

Suggestion for your code:
You don't need extra function just to print the result I have modified your code a little checkout:

```
def get_specials(day,time):
    special_dish = {"monday": {"B": "Horseradish omelet. Note: better than it sounds",
                      "L": "Momma's Curry. Note: Can be made spicy.",
                      "D": "Beef brisket. Note: COmes with au jus. That's pronounced 'Oh jhoo', not 'Ow Juice'"},
           "tuesday": {"B": "Sausage gravy over biscuits. Note: Toast can be subbed",
                       "L": "Grilled cheese and tomato soup. Note: We have vegan cheese",
                       "D": "Meatloaf. Note: Comes woth catsup on the top. Not optional"},
           "wednesday": {"B": "Horseradish omelet. Note: better than it sounds",
                         "L": "Momma's Curry. Note: Can be made spicy.",
                         "D": "Beef brisket. Note: COmes with au jus. That's pronounced 'Oh jhoo', not 'Ow Juice'"},
           "thursday": {"B": "Sausage gravy over biscuits. Note: Toast can be subbed",
                        "L": "Grilled cheese and tomato soup. Note: We have vegan cheese",
                        "D": "Meatloaf. Note: Comes woth catsup on the top. Not optional"},
           "friday": {"B": "Horseradish omelet. Note: better than it sounds",
                      "L": "Momma's Curry. Note: Can be made spicy.",
                      "D": "Beef brisket. Note: COmes with au jus. That's pronounced 'Oh jhoo', not 'Ow Juice'"},
           "saturday": {"B": "Sausage gravy over biscuits. Note: Toast can be subbed",
                        "L": "Grilled cheese and tomato soup. Note: We have vegan cheese",
                        "D": "Meatloaf. Note: Comes woth catsup on the top. Not optional"}}

    specials = {"M": "monday",
                "T": "tuesday",
                "W": "wednesday",
                "R": "thursday",
                "F": "friday",
                "St": "saturday"}
    get_day=specials.get(day)
    get_special=special_dish.get(get_day).get(time)
    return "The special is: {}".format(get_special)



def get_day():
    while True:
        day = input ("Day (M/T/W/R/F/St): ")
        if day.upper() in ["M", "T", "W", "R", "F", "ST"]:
            return day.upper()
        else:
            print ("I'm sorry, but {} isn't valid".format(day))

def get_time():
    while True:
        time = input ("Time (B/L/D): ")
        if time.upper() in ["B", "L", "D"]:
            return time.upper()
        else:
            print ("I'm sorry, but {} isn't valid".format(time))

def main():

    print ("This script will tell you the specials for any day and time of the week")
    while True:
        day = get_day()
        time = get_time()
        print(get_specials(day,time))

# ********************^^^^ HERE ^^^*
        another = input("Do you want to check another day and time?(Y/N): ")
        if another.lower == "n":
            break

main()
```

output:

```
This script will tell you the specials for any day and time of the week
Day (M/T/W/R/F/St): M
Time (B/L/D): B
The special is:Horseradish omelet. Note: better than it sounds
Do you want to check another day and time?(Y/N):
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I ran the code and it come out as an error 
(NameError: name 'm' is not defined). I changed input to raw_input and it worked.